# call: Warning: Unused local variable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, error

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MKotET1_1{
   address payable king; uint public claimPrice = 100;

   function calculateCompensation() public returns(uint) {
}

function( ) external payable {
   if (msg.value  < claimPrice) revert();
      uint compensation = calculateCompensation();
      (bool success, bytes memory returnMessage) = 
      king.call.value(compensation)("");
      require(success); 
      king = msg.sender;
   }
}
```

I am getting following warning message:

> > solc MKotET_stackExchange.sol
> >     MKotET_stackExchange.sol:11:26: Warning: Unused local variable.
> >               (bool success, bytes memory returnMessage) = king.call.value(compensation)("");
> >                              ^------------------------^

Somebody please guide me how to remove this warning message.

Zulfi.

Comment: Why do you want to silence the warning?

Comment: Contract owner won't like it. Also warning means something wrong going on, not good from software engineering point of view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly state the second variable declaration. You can write it as follows:

```
(bool success, ) = king.call.value(compensation)("");
require(success);
```